# Transferring Clash of Clans

Tags: ios, game-center, clash-of-clans

I originally started playing Clash of Clans on a first-generation iPad and connected it to my GameCenter.
I then got a third generation iPad, linked it to the first iPad's GameCenter account, and continued playing Clash of Clans on the new iPad 3.
My friend is giving me his GameCenter account, which is linked to HIS Clash of Clans village- is there any way I can transfer his village to my Game Center ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you can:

- sign into your our Game Center on your iPad 3
- delete the app from the original iPad (making a backup first)
- sign into your friend's Game Center on your iPad
- reload the game and verify the correct village loaded

Once that is done, you should have both villages intact.

Answer (score 0):

You will only lose that village from the device, on your iPad 3 everything will be fine.

Jush log out in the game and from gamecenter and then let him log in.