# How to transfer Clash of Clans from one iOS device to another

Tags: ios, game-center, clash-of-clans

I have two iPhones and an iPad 2. One of the phones is an iPhone 3GS running iOS 6.1.6 and the other is an iPhone 4 running iOS 7. Under the same Game Center account they each have a separate village for Clash of Clans. I just got my iPad and wanted to transfer the game on the iOS 6.1.6 device to my iPad. What I was wondering was, if it's even possible to link a game on Clash of Clans from an iOS 6 device to an iOS 7 device, and if so how do I do so?

Comment: We really didn't get a good answer on [this similar question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114951/transferring-clash-of-clans). Perhaps we need someone to just [ask the developer how to move a village](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Device_Linking_Guide) and pop up an answer here?

Comment: This is old but it's recently changed I have have had to do this recently.  In iOS there is now a 'connect Supercell ID' option.  I moved my account from my iPhone to my iPad by clicking this button in the in game settings.  I had to do the normal register email mumbo jumbo.  Once done I installed CoC on my iPad; completed the tutorial; went into settings and clicked the same 'Supercell ID' button and logged in using the same email.  It promted me "are you sure you want to overwrite this new villiage. I clicked yes and boom.  Done.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. All you need to do is have both your devices next to that you want to make the transfer with. Then tap the settings button in clash of clans and you will see "link a device". Follow the on screen instructions after that.

If you have a new account already made on your new device past town hall 4 you are unable to link them. You will need to contact supercell for further information, which is what I had to do.

Answer (score 0):

With a 3rd party USB iPhone file viewing application on your Mac or PC, such as iExplorer or DiskAid, one can try copying all the files from an app on one iOS device to your Mac, and then copy them all of them onto the other iOS device.  To be safe, force-quit the apps on both devices first and do a complete backup of the target device before trying this method, as it can potentially completely mess up an app, and require it to be deleted and re-installed.

Answer (score 0):

CoC can be transferred with the "link a device"-option.

Another way to do this is by using the same apple id for gamecenter.

You can change the apple id under Game Center in settings>game center.

Via this way it will also be possible to transfer account that are linked to gamecenter, but do not have an "link a device" option built in.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download iExplore on your computer.
2. Connect your old iOS device to your computer, browse to /private/var/mobile/Containers folder then copy the Clash of Clans folder to somewhere in your computer.
3. Connect the new device then copy that folder to /private/var/mobile/Containers (iOS7) or /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application (iOS8).
4. Login with your related Game Center ID.
5. It will ask you if you want to play that Clash of Clans account or not.

Source: http://cocland.com/tutorials/transfer-clash-of-clans-from-old-ios-devices

Answer (score -1):

The new version will fix the problem is not loaded games

Answer (score -1):

Maybe can be possible making a backup with iTools and restoring into the new one.

Comment: Good start, can you expand your answer with more details please