# How to transfer Clash of Clans account from one Game Center user to another

Tags: games, game-center, clash-of-clans

*This is not a question about transferring from one iOS device to another (straightforward and addressed at length in [How to transfer Clash of Clans from one iOS device to another](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126884/). This is a question about transferring **from one Game Center account to another**. It happens that in my case this is within a given device.*

My kid has started to play Clash of Clans on my iPad - under my own Game Center account.   Now I have reconfigured this iPad for him to use, with his own account (which I created in order to use the Family Sharing features.

How do I transfer his CoC village from my Game Center account to his?

Answer (score 1):

You can contact coc support and they can help you transfer it.

It's not something you can do without their help.